Issue with Email Verification Status in Firebase 2FA Implementation
I am implementing two-factor authentication (2FA) with email in Firebase using Next.js. Initially, when a user signs in with a new email, the emailVerified field is false, which correctly triggers the authentication process. However, on subsequent logins with the same email, Firebase sets the emailVerified field to true, indicating that the email has been verified.
My issue is that I want the emailVerified field to always return false on every login, even for users who have already verified their email, so that the user is prompted for re-authentication every time they log in.
This is necessary to ensure that the 2FA process is triggered on each login attempt.
const handleLogin = async (e: React.FormEvent) => {
const handleLogin = async (e: React.FormEvent) => {
 e.preventDefault();
  setLoading(true);

  try {
    const userCredential = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
    const user = userCredential.user;
    if (!user.emailVerified) {
      await sendEmailVerification(user);
      setVerificationSent(true);
      setToast('Please check your email for verification link');
      startVerificationCheck(user);
      return;
    }

    await fetchUserDetails(user.uid, user);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Login failed:', error);
    setToast('Login failed! Please check your credentials.');
  } finally {
    setLoading(false);
  }
};

const startVerificationCheck = (user: any) => {
  // Check every 5 seconds for up to 5 minutes if email is verified
  const intervalId = setInterval(async () => {
    setVerificationChecks((prev) => prev + 1);
    // Reload user to get latest emailVerified status
    await user?.reload();
    if (user?.emailVerified) {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
      setVerificationSent(false);
      await fetchUserDetails(user.uid, user);
    }

    // Stop checking after 60 attempts (5 minutes)
    if (verificationChecks >= 60) {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
      setVerificationSent(false);
      setToast('Email verification timeout. Please try logging in again.');
      await auth.signOut();
    }
  }, 5000);
};

const fetchUserDetails = async (uid: string, user: any) => {
  try {
    const docRef = doc(db, 'users', uid);
    const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

    if (docSnap.exists()) {
      const data = docSnap.data();
      const fullName = data?.name || 'User';
      const role = data?.role;
      const idToken = await user.getIdToken();

      setAuth(role, fullName, idToken);
      router.push('/');
    } else {
      console.error('No such user!');
      setToast('No user found.');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching user data:', error);
    setToast('Error fetching user data');
    await auth.signOut();
  }
};


I highly doubt you can change the behavior of the emailVerified value. It already has well-defined behavior and is not meant to be used for 2FA.  There are other ways to do 2FA, which are covered in the documentation for SMS and TOTP.


I want the emailVerified field to always return false on every login, even for users who have already verified their email

That's simply not how Firebase Authentication's built-in email verification flow works, and (as Doug also commented) there is no way to change this behavior in the way you want.
If you're willing to write server-side code, you might be able to implement the use-case with a blocking Cloud Function that hooks beforeSignIn and clear the emailVerified claim at that point.
